# Facebook Credits - Tester

Tags: facebook, credits

I have an application set up that uses facebook credits set up with a couple of tester-users so we can validate everything works.

We're also tracking revenue in our system, this presents a problem with tester-accounts as their purchase are not "real".

Is there some way to differentiate in the call-back ? (I figure worst case I can white-list several FB-ids to not count for our reports, but this is sort of a hack).

Comment: Next time please use the answer field instead of the comments.

Comment: Wasn't allowed.. says I need to wait 8 hours :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook callback will contain a field called 'test_mode' set to 1.